# How to insert different stylesheet depending of the page in MediaWiki?

Tags: php, css, mediawiki

How can I include a custom css stylesheet to some pages?

I have /wiki/Home_Page with standard css and Vector theme, but I'd like some page to have a different css file. Right now I'm editing Common.css like that:

```
.rootpage-Page1 {
  background-image: url("...");
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.rootpage-Page1 .gallerytextwrapper {
  background-color: rgba(40,40,40,0.8) !important;
}
.rootpage-Page1 a {
  color: lightblue;
}
.rootpage-Page2 {
  background-image: url("...");
}
```

The [CSS extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CSS) form the MediaWiki website doesn't works. I see the `{{#css}}` tags in my articles. It's mainly changing the colors of some stuff to fit the theme of the article and it's subpages.

Answer (score 1):

[TemplateStyles](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TemplateStyles) would be one option; it allows the use of a (relatively) safe, sanitized subset of CSS on wiki pages.